# Can diabetes relieve symptoms of hemophilia?

Tags: diabetes

This question can be seen silly, but I wondered about this question for several years. I learned that diabetes make our blood so sticky that it can block blood flows of capillary vessels. Then, what happens if a hemobohilia patient with diabetes accidently cut his (because there are few female hemophilia patients) toe's skin with a cutter,  paper or glass fragment? Does the sticky blood caused by diabetes help stopping bleeding the area?  Yeah, I know that blood coagulation factors like pibrin are the primary factors for stopping bleeding, but I want to know the effects of sticky blood caused by diabetes on cut area.

P.S. Sorry for poor English.

Comment: Welcome to Health, KYHSGeekCode! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. What has your prior research on this revealed to you so far?  You may improve your question to comply with site guidelines with an [edit] and the help of [ask]. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I will study more in help center and research more about the topic. Then I'll be able to improve my question. Thanks.

Comment: You're confusing concepts.